# Posting a null validation from drop down list MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working to develop an application asp.net MVC that has a text box and two drop down lists. Users can input a numeric value and choose from the list from - to to process . My problem is trying to validate the drop down list as I tried to use the required validation but didn't work. I also tried to check on the drop downs when sending null values but the error validation doesn't work!

The error type:

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'fromCurrency.Name'.
```

Contorller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Currencies cur)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {



                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cur.fromCurrency.Name) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cur.toCurrency.Name))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "you can not leave the empty dropdown please select any of these");
                }


                else
                {

                    var fromCurrencyList = CurrenciesClient.GetFromCurrencyListAsync().Result;

                    ViewBag.FromCurrencies = new SelectList(fromCurrencyList, "CurrencyCode", "Name");

                    var ToCurrencyList = CurrenciesClient.GetToCurrencyListAsync().Result;

                    ViewBag.ToCurrencies = new SelectList(ToCurrencyList, "CurrencyCode", "Name");


                    var fromcurrname = cur.fromCurrency.Name;
                    string tocurrname = cur.toCurrency.Name;

                    //rate is taking by passing both dropdown currency code
                    decimal rate = CurrenciesClient.GetConversionRate("Currencies/GetConversionRate?fromcurrname=" + fromcurrname + "&tocurrname=" + tocurrname).Result;
                    ViewBag.TheResult = cur.CurrencyToConvert * rate;


                }

            }
            return View();
        }
```

Index View

```
@model ViewModel.Currencies

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div id="ConversionSection">

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id= "CurrencyConversion" action="/Currency/Index">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrencyToConvert, "Enter Currency")
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CurrencyToConvert, new { @class = " form-control" })
                    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrencyToConvert)*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrencyToConvert, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fromCurrency.Name, "From Currency")
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.fromCurrency.Name, ViewBag.FromCurrencies as SelectList, "--select--", new { @class = " form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fromCurrency.Name)

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.toCurrency.Name, "To Currency")
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.toCurrency.Name, ViewBag.ToCurrencies as SelectList, "--select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.toCurrency.Name)*@

                    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                         @Html.LabelFor(l => l.ConvertedCurrency, "Value")
                     </label>
                     <div class="col-sm-4">
                         @Html.Editor("TheResult", new { @class = " form-control" })
                     </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>


    </div>
```

Currencies.cs

```
    public class Currencies
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        public decimal CurrencyToConvert { get; set; }


        public Currency fromCurrency { get; set; }

        public Currency toCurrency { get; set; }

        public double ConvertedCurrency { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nothing is return if your modelstate will be invalid. So `viewbag.FromCurrencies` and `Viewbag.ToCurrencies` should be outside of  `if (ModelState.IsValid)`.If you will not add Viewbag properties code after `if(ModelState.IsValid)` null value will be passed through it and you will get this exception. I am writing here refactored code in `httppost` method.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ConvertCurrencyViewModel cur)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                    string fromcurrname = cur.fromCurrency.Name;
                    string tocurrname = cur.toCurrency.Name;

                    //rate is taking by passing both dropdown currency code
                    decimal rate = CurrencyClient.GetConversionRate("Currency/GetConversionRate?fromcurrname=" + fromcurrname + "&tocurrname=" + tocurrname).Result;
                    ViewBag.result = cur.CurrencyToConvert * rate;

            }
                //getting this select list value form Currency client class
                var fromCurrencyList = CurrencyClient.GetFromCurrencyListAsync().Result;

                ViewBag.FromCurrencies = new SelectList(fromCurrencyList, "CurrencyCode", "Name");

                var ToCurrencyList = CurrencyClient.GetToCurrencyListAsync().Result;

                ViewBag.ToCurrencies = new SelectList(ToCurrencyList, "CurrencyCode", "Name");

                return View();

        }
```

And modifiy your curreny class like this to show validation error.

```
public class Currencies
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter amount to convert")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        public decimal CurrencyToConvert { get; set; }


        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please select country Name")]
        public Currency fromCurrency { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please select country Name")]
        public Currency toCurrency { get; set; }

        public double ConvertedCurrency { get; set; }
    }
```

This will help you to validate your fields.

Comment: Everything is working just fine! Thank you very much for answering the question.